# Laravel extracting elements from collection, and sort it

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i have a Collection like that:

```
+----------+----------+
| user_id  |  city_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |
|      ... |      ... |
|      901 |        2 |
|      902 |        2 |
|      ... |      ... |
|     1501 |        3 |
|     1502 |        3 |
|      ... |      ... |
+----------+----------+
```

in this example i have

**900** users for **city_id = 1**
**600** users for **city_id = 2**
**300** users for **city_id = 3**

what i want to do:

Sort each user in a fair way, so that I end up with a list like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id |  city_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       2 |        1 |
|       3 |        1 |
|     901 |        2 |
|     902 |        2 |
|    1501 |        3 |
|       4 |        1 |
|       5 |        1 |
|       6 |        1 |
|     903 |        2 |
|     904 |        2 |
|    1502 |        3 |
+---------+----------+
```

I divided everything by 300 (for example), so i have by day:

**3** users from **city 1** 
then **2** users from **city 2** 
then **1** user from **city 3** 
then **3** users from **city 1** 
then **2** users from **city 2** 
then **1** user from **city 3** 
...

I tried to use the take() function but it doesnt modify the original collection.
And i used the shift() function but it just take one item.

i tried that code:

```
while($users->isNotEmpty()){
    // $user->count() = 1800
    for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
        $final->push($users->where('city_id', 1)->shift());
    }
    for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
        $final->push($users->where('city_id', 2)->shift());
    }
    $final->push($users->where('city_id', 3)->shift());

    // $user->count() = 1800; $final->count() = 6
}
```

it doesn't shift element from $user collection. still have 1800 elements...

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to resort your result or get chunk of the records ? Explain your requirement in a sentence

Comment: the results in one list

Comment: collection already gives a results in one list. 
Your requirement table is unclear. Neither user_id is sorted nor city_id. Anyhow if your want to sort array on the basis of keys then try these php array sorting functions based on keys e.g. usort(), uasort() or uksort().